# Jackson + SugarOrm id error

Tags: android, jackson, sugarorm

I use jackson and sugar orm and i have some errors when parsing. The id field is located in the json constantly 0. What can I do to fix it?

This example my class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class JsonScienceEvent extends SugarRecord<JsonScienceEvent>{

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String eventId;

public JsonScienceEvent()

public JsonScienceEvent(String eventId){
    this.eventId = eventId;
}

public String getEventId(){
    return eventId;
}
```

Comment: Post the error stack

Comment: also post the json that you are trying to parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the field`id` is inherited from the super class `SugarRecord<T>` along with the setter and getter methods `setId(Long id)` and `getId()`.
You can `override` the `id` field generated by the Sugar library, but as far as i can remember it uses `Long` type so if you can change from String identifier to Long all should be fine and, this way you can force the library to use the `id` you're setting with the setter `setId(Long id)`,

Answer (score 0):

Sugar ORM actually creates its own ID field to maintain. If you're not inserting a value into the eventId field when creating a record, then your column is empty.

Try using "**getId()**" to get the auto incremented ID from the record. Don't forget to cast to a string if that's what you want back!